# Noun to describe state of a word’s capitalization

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun to describe the state of a word’s capitalization? I can think of " ‘lower-casedness’ or ‘upper-casesness’ ", but is there a more succinct expression?

Comment: I guess *case* could have two states: *upper* and *lower*.  "What is the case of this letter?" ...   "Upper case."

Comment: How about "wealth"?  (And "Upper Caisse" and "Lower Caisse" are the islands of the island nation [San Serrife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Serriffe).)

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a noun to describe the state of a word’s capitalization?" A **word** can be, in ordinary text, capitalised: Queen, all lower-case: queen, all upper case (or all capitals/"all caps"): QUEEN. I suppose a noun phrase to describe this might be 'capitalisation state'. I spell 'capitalise' the British way.

Comment: Upper or lower. Could you please compose this in a meaningful sentence as part of your answer?

Comment: I would just say **capitalized**. (Or, **not capitalized**.) Which is different from "all caps."

Answer (score -1):

On web pages it is called the CSS text-transform. There are currently

`uppercase`, `lowercase`, and `capitalize`.

Of course that is specific to how web page programmers talk about it.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Answer (score -1):

majuscule

as opposed to

minuscule

majuscule
A large letter, either capital or uncial, used in writing or printing.
[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/majuscule)

minuscule
3. A lowercase letter.
[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/majuscule)

> Letter case (or just case) is the distinction between the letters that
>   are in larger upper case (also uppercase, capital letters, capitals,
>   caps, large letters, or more formally majuscule) and smaller lower
>   case (also lowercase, small letters, or more formally minuscule) in
>   the written representation of certain languages
>  [Letter case
>   (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)

Edit: If you want the word that describes both upper case and lower case characters, then the word you're looking is "letter case" or just "case". If however you want to say that letters are written in upper-case, you can call them upper case or majuscule.

majuscule can either by noun or adjective:

> n (Printing, Lithography & Bookbinding) a large letter, either capital
>   or uncial, used in printing or writing 
>   adj (Printing, Lithography &
>   Bookbinding) relating to, printed, or written in such letters. Compare
>   minuscule
>   [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/majuscule)

So you can say the word or letters are typed or written in majuscule, or you can simply refer to the letters as majuscule if you want.

These are technical terms, you'd be clearer with "upper case", which can mean what you said "upper-casedness".

Comment: I believe that majuscule and minuscule are instances of what was requested. Please refine your answer.

Comment: Perhaps "sculishness".